# Check for set membership in a SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>

Tags: c#

I am using `Contains` method on `SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>` to check for existence of `SortedSet<int>`(call it, `Itemset`). Sample code is as follows:

```
Itemset j = new Itemset() { 1, 2 };
Itemset i = new Itemset() { 1, 3 };
SortedSet<Itemset> ItemsetCollection = new SortedSet<Itemset>();
ItemsetCollection.Add(i);
ItemsetCollection.Add(j);
```

If I have an itemset exactly similar to say, `i` and check for its membership in `ItemsetCollection` using `Contains` as shown below the check returns a `false` as it expects the name to be same as `i`

```
Itemset iset = new Itemset(){1,2};
bool b = ItemsetCollection.Contains(iset);
```

How else can the membership be checked if I am generating itemsets randomly and need to check for its presence in `ItemSetCollection`?

Comment: A `SortedSet<SortedSet<int>>` makes no sense unless you provide the outer `SortedSet` a custom `IComparer<SortedSet<int>>`.  Otherwise how exactly do you think it's sorting the inner sets and do you even really need to sort a collection of sets in the first place?  Finally renaming a class type in your code is profoundly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ItemsetCollection.Any(it => it.Count == iset.Count
                            && it.All(ti => iset.Any(tti => ti == tti)));
```